# Which mosquito species is this?

Tags: species-identification

Today, when I just woke up and saw this. I need to identify the species of this mosquito. I don't think its dangerous like Female Anopheles. I'm afraid if it is a carrier of any dangerous diseases such as Filaria, Dengue, etc.

[image]

Location: Bokaro, Jharkhand, India

Temprature: $ 29°C $

Comment: It is a female. From Wikipedia: "Anopheles mosquitoes can be distinguished from other mosquitoes by the palps, which are as long as the proboscis,and by the presence of discrete blocks of black and white scales on the wings." I can't see the palps for sure, but they look short (if what I am seeing are the palps).

Comment: @Karl Is it Anopheles?

Comment: I don't know because I cannot clearly see the palps. Mosquitos are not my specialty though, and I am sure that an expert will be better able to tell.